# Validar entrada en un JTable (Java)

Tags: java, jtable

Tengo un problema con JTable: tengo una tabla con las columnas CODIGO, DESCRIPCION, CANTIDAD, PRECIO, CATALOGO, y NUMERO_PAGINA, y necesito que las columnas codigo, cantidad, precio solo acepten números. He probado con los eventos y no logro solucionar.

Éste es mi código:

```
public Principal() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, ParseException {
        initComponents();

        SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin("org.jvnet.substance.skin.BusinessBlackSteelSkin");
        //agrega los campos a la tabla
        String [] col = {"Codigo","Descripción","Cantidad","Precio","Catálogo","#Página"};
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(col,1);

        tabla.setModel(modelo);
        frameIngresaOrden.dispose();
        frameModOrdenes.dispose();
        frameVerOrdenes.dispose();
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Pane.add(frameIngresaOrden);
        Pane.add(frameModOrdenes);
        Pane.add(frameVerOrdenes);

         TableColumn catalogo = tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
         TableColumn numeroPag = tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);

         comboBox.addItem("ÉSIKA");
         comboBox.addItem("CYZONE");
         comboBox.addItem("L'BEL");

         llenarComboBox();

         catalogo.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
         numeroPag.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox2));

        int rw=tabla.getSelectionModel().getMinSelectionIndex();
        int cl=tabla.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();


    }
```

En realidad no llevo gran parte de código porque estaba diseñando la interfaz y de ahí partir programar la entrada de datos. Dejo la imagen como referencia; la idea es llenar los datos celda por celda:

[image: Interfaz]

Comment: Deberias de mostrar tu codigo y enseñar que llevas, es muy complicado saber de que forma ingresaras tus valores a la tabla.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía __[ask]__ y de ser posible, agrega un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1):

Establece el tipo de campo en el modelo de la tabla

```
tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        null,
        new String [] {
            //Defines TODOS los nombres de las columnas que tendrá la tabla
            "Codigo", "Cantidad","Nombre","Precio"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            //Defines el tipo que admitirá la COLUMNA, cada uno con el índice correspondiente
            //Codigo (Integer), Cantidad (Integer), Nombre (String), Precio(Double)
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Double.class
        };

        //Función que asignará el tipo de campo que asignaste previamente
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
```